# Допустимы ли общие вопросы с собеседований

Tags: обсуждение

Стоит ли задавать вопросы с собеседований такие как: что такое технология X отличия от технологии Y, плюсы и минусы и т. д. По-хорошему они есть в докуменатации, но без развернутой информации про плюсы минусы.

Comment: Мне кажется что не стоит, так как на них нельзя ответить однозначно. Такие вопросы обычно вызывают дискуссии.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Причины, побуждающие задать вопрос, никому не интересны.
Поэтому, конечно, можно и с собеседований, и с дружеских бесед.

---

Однако, вопросы типа "Чем X лучше Y? Плюсы/минусы." определённо не соответствуют формату сайта (за редким исключением).
Более конкретные вопросы ("Почему X имеет так же Y, хотя уже есть вроде бы идентичное Z?") только приветствуются.